# Question deleted of its own accord?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

What happened to this question? [Password protect my internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055830/password-protect-my-internet) (10k only.)

Deleted questions usually have the list of people (or Community) who did the deletion, but this one shows no-one, and the user appears to have been deleted too. I don't see that question in the list or recently deleted posts in the 10k tools.

The question doesn't have the

> Browse other questions tagged [this] [or] [that] or ask your own question.

footer either (in Chrome 17 or Firefox 9 on Linux - starting to think this could be front-end related).

What can cause a question not to have the usual deletion note?

<sub>Note: This is *not* a request to undelete that post.</sub>

Comment: Automagically torched due to extremely low quality?

Comment: It might have been auto-deleted with the user's account.  I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A mod destroyed the user account.

Comment: Yup; and since the account no longer exists, the (presumed) self-user-deletion would have no valid context to show "deleted by ___".

Comment: @AndrewBarber: No; destroying an account deletes all of its posts without attribution.

Comment: Ahh! I almost put a question mark on my comment; I should have! Thanks for the correction/clarification!